# Data.table single thread warning

Tags: r, data.table, homebrew

I am working on a mac with catalina 10.15.5, having updated R recently there is now a warning when I call data.table which indicates it is single-threading. I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), removed the package and reinstalled from cran, however, the warning remains and getDTthreads() still returns 1 (even following stDTthreads(2)).
How can I resolve this issue?

the notice is

```
remove.packages("data.table")
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.8 using 1 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
**********
This installation of data.table has not detected OpenMP support. 
It should still work but in single-threaded mode. 
If this is a Mac, please ensure you are using R>=3.4.0 and have followed our Mac instructions here:
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation. 
This warning message should not occur on Windows or Linux. If it does, please file a GitHub issue.
**********

getDTthreads()
[1] 1
```

My sessioninfo (after calling library) is

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.12.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2
```

and my user/.R/Makevars has

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc64
CXX = /usr/bin/g++
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp


# if you downloaded llvm manually above, replace with your chosen NEW_PATH/clang
LLVM_LOC = /usr/local/opt/llvm
CC=$(LLVM_LOC)/bin/clang -fopenmp
CXX=$(LLVM_LOC)/bin/clang++ -fopenmp
# -O3 should be faster than -O2 (default) level optimisation ..
CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L$(LLVM_LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LLVM_LOC)/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I$(LLVM_LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

Edit:

```
install.packages("data.table", type = "source")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/data.table_1.12.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4948391 bytes (4.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
*** pkg-config is installed but 'pkg-config --exists zlib' did not return 0.
*** Compilation will now be attempted and if it works you can ignore this message. However,
*** if compilation fails, try 'locate zlib.h zconf.h' and ensure the zlib development library
*** is installed :
***   deb: zlib1g-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
***   rpm: zlib-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
***   brew: zlib (OSX)
*** Note that zlib is required to compile R itself so you may find the advice in the R-admin
*** guide helpful regarding zlib. On Debian/Ubuntu, zlib1g-dev is a dependency of r-base as
*** shown by 'apt-cache showsrc r-base | grep ^Build-Depends | grep zlib', and therefore
*** 'sudo apt-get build-dep r-base' should be sufficient too.
*** To silence this message, please ensure that :
***   1) 'pkg-config --exists zlib' succeeds (i.e. $? -eq 0)
***   2) 'pkg-config --libs zlib' contains -lz
*** Compilation will now be attempted ...
** libs
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c assign.c -o assign.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c between.c -o between.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c bmerge.c -o bmerge.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c chmatch.c -o chmatch.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c cj.c -o cj.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c coalesce.c -o coalesce.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c dogroups.c -o dogroups.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c fastmean.c -o fastmean.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c fcast.c -o fcast.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c fifelse.c -o fifelse.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c fmelt.c -o fmelt.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c forder.c -o forder.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c frank.c -o frank.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c fread.c -o fread.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c freadR.c -o freadR.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c froll.c -o froll.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c frollR.c -o frollR.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c frolladaptive.c -o frolladaptive.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c fsort.c -o fsort.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c fwrite.c -o fwrite.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c fwriteR.c -o fwriteR.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c gsumm.c -o gsumm.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c ijoin.c -o ijoin.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c init.c -o init.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c inrange.c -o inrange.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c nafill.c -o nafill.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c nqrecreateindices.c -o nqrecreateindices.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c openmp-utils.c -o openmp-utils.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c quickselect.c -o quickselect.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c rbindlist.c -o rbindlist.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c reorder.c -o reorder.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c shift.c -o shift.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c subset.c -o subset.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c transpose.c -o transpose.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c types.c -o types.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c uniqlist.c -o uniqlist.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c utils.c -o utils.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c vecseq.c -o vecseq.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c wrappers.c -o wrappers.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o data.table.so assign.o between.o bmerge.o chmatch.o cj.o coalesce.o dogroups.o fastmean.o fcast.o fifelse.o fmelt.o forder.o frank.o fread.o freadR.o froll.o frollR.o frolladaptive.o fsort.o fwrite.o fwriteR.o gsumm.o ijoin.o init.o inrange.o nafill.o nqrecreateindices.o openmp-utils.o quickselect.o rbindlist.o reorder.o shift.o subset.o transpose.o types.o uniqlist.o utils.o vecseq.o wrappers.o -lz -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
mv data.table.so datatable.so
if [ "" != "Windows_NT" ] && [ `uname -s` = 'Darwin' ]; then install_name_tool -id datatable.so datatable.so; fi
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-data.table/00new/data.table/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (data.table)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/2p/75d89bf97ml3frtv1ylcw3nw0000gn/T/RtmpXjVzPR/downloaded_packages’
 
library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.8 using 1 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
**********
This installation of data.table has not detected OpenMP support. It should still work but in single-threaded mode. If this is a Mac, please ensure you are using R>=3.4.0 and have followed our Mac instructions here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation. This warning message should not occur on Windows or Linux. If it does, please file a GitHub issue.
**********
```

Comment: can you try `install.packages('data.table', type='source')` and share the output of the installation? there are a couple of threads about installation on Mac which has become more difficult: [1](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4471) [2](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4574) [3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4437) [4](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4348) [5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4016)

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question to include the output, I hadn't seen the threads before, I will take a look

Comment: If you're trying to use data.table with openmp support on macOS Big Sur, instructions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340

Answer (score 0):

## Activate multithread calculations using data.table

This is based on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5419).

This works with Mac silicon chip M series.

1. Remove any data.table packages from `r`
2. Use the terminal to do the following (use `homebrew` to install the following packages):

   ```
   brew install libomp
   brew install pkg-config
   mkdir ~/.R
   nano ~/.R/Makevars
   ```
3. Paste the following into nano (`~/.R/Makevars`) and save

   ```
   LDFLAGS += -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib -lomp
   CPPFLAGS += -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -Xclang -fopenmp
   ```
4. Install data.table from source within `r`

   ```
   install.packages("data.table", type = "source")
   ```