# clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 for macOS Big Sur

Tags: r, macos, clang, macos-big-sur

Installing R packages that need compiling in macOS is broken since Big Sur.  Here is such an example.

```
> install.packages('nlme')

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary  source needs_compilation
nlme 3.1-150 3.1-151              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘nlme’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/nlme_3.1-151.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 805592 bytes (786 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 786 KB

* installing *source* package ‘nlme’ ...
** package ‘nlme’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
"gfortran-4.8" -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c chol.f -o chol.o
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘20.1.0
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c corStruct.c -o corStruct.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c gnls.c -o gnls.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c matrix.c -o matrix.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c nlOptimizer.c -o nlOptimizer.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c nlme.c -o nlme.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c nlmefit.c -o nlmefit.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c pdMat.c -o pdMat.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c pythag.c -o pythag.o
"gfortran-4.8" -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c rs.f -o rs.o
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘20.1.0
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o nlme.so chol.o corStruct.o gnls.o init.o matrix.o nlOptimizer.o nlme.o nlmefit.o pdMat.o pythag.o rs.o  -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: framework not found CoreFoundation
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [nlme.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nlme’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/nlme’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/nlme’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nlme’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/_3/b8whcf8d1bb8w_lr2rrscb5m0000gp/T/RtmpWCjwfs/downloaded_packages’
```

I've tried reinstalling xcode and Command Line Tools and completed Brew update + upgrade.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Just spotted this (ignored) question which looks related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047685/r-package-installation-fail-ld-framework-not-found-corefoundation-clang-7-err

Comment: Lots of other people stumbling upon the same issue. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EbLLgorUcAEpWYf?format=png&name=900x900

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM. Though very fristrating!

Comment: Might be better to communicate with the R-MAC-sig mailing list.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. I've tried 
`r-macos-rtools` but the installation does not work for Big Sur. Here is some info  on how to fix the installation, though I was not able to: https://github.com/rmacoslib/r-macos-rtools/issues/42

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This has been challenging, but here are the steps I used compile R packages from source on MacOS Big Sur:

1. Reinstall xcode command line tools

(don't believe Software Update if it says 'up to date' - he lies - `brew doctor` said my version was actually old)

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

2. Install gcc & llvm via Homebrew ([instructions for installing Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)) or, if you already have gcc/llvm installed, skip to the next step

```
# WARNING: This can take several hours
brew install gcc
brew install llvm
```

3. If you already have gcc & llvm installed via Homebrew:

```
brew cleanup
brew update
brew upgrade
brew reinstall gcc
brew reinstall llvm
```

4. Link some headers into /usr/local/include

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/* /usr/local/include/

# I believe you can safely ignore warnings like this:
#ln: /usr/local/include//tcl.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclPlatDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMath.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMathDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tk.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tkDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tkPlatDecls.h: File exists
```

5. Edit your `~/.R/Makevars` file to include only these lines:

```
LOC=/usr/local/gfortran
CC=$(LOC)/bin/gcc -fopenmp
CXX=$(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp
CXX11 = $(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp

CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
LDFLAGS=-L$(LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LOC)/lib,-L/usr/local/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I$(LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/include

FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
CXX1X=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX98=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX11=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX14=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX17=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
```

6. Compile a package from source in R/Rstudio

```
# Compile the nlme package from source
install.packages("nlme", type = "source")

# To check whether openmp is enabled, compile data.table:
install.packages("data.table", type = "source")
```

### Edit Sept 2023

Updating macOS to Ventura appears to have broken the compiler toolchain (again). Trying to build a package from source gave the error:

```
ld: unsupported mach-o filetype (only MH_OBJECT and MH_DYLIB can be linked) in '/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [data.table.so] Error 1
Call `pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` to diagnose the problem.
```

@obruzzi suggested deleting the new SDK in their answer below (which would then default to the v13.3 SDK), but generally this isn't good practice as you want the most up-to-date tools so that they 'work together' properly.

The solution that I would recommend is to reinstall the command line tools and gcc (Steps 1, 2 and 3, as described above), then edit your ~/.R/Makevars to:

```
LOC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0
CC=$(LOC)/bin/gcc-13 -fopenmp
CXX=$(LOC)/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX11=$(LOC)/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp

CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
LDFLAGS=-L$(LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LOC)/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I$(LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/include

# Previous vars
FLIBS=-L$(LOC)/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/ -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
CXX1X=$(LOC)/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX98=$(LOC)/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX11=$(LOC)/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX14=$(LOC)/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
CXX17=$(LOC)/bin/g++-13 -fopenmp
```

Then, running `pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` returned `Your system is ready to build packages!` and data.table compiled with openMP support as expected.

Comment: Thanks Jared, I get `$ git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow
fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense` Any idea why?

Comment: My homebrew is currently a mess due to QGIS, but hopefully once I've resolved that in next day or so your solution will work.

Comment: Brew fixed and your workflow fixed this install.  Many thanks :)

Comment: After doing all this I still get the error about `ld: framework not found CoreFoundation`

Comment: Trying to figure out why it didn't work.... one thing is that my version of gfortran seems to be using the libraries of a different gcc version to that specified in the Makevars file above. Mine has `/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0`. Changing the makevars to use that doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Have now gone through it all again both in whole, and rerunning `brew reinstall gcc` again after seeing your message.. I still have the x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0 folder there. Any suggestions would be very, very welcome!

Comment: Just noticed that when I run `reinstall gcc` it seems to pour it to `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0`. Any idea why it would use this address instead?

Comment: After all steps and restarting I got `ld: framework not found CoreFoundation`. Installing fresh gfortran for R/Mac worked for me: https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/10.2-bigsur-intel

Comment: @speleo, that's it! Installing gfortran from that link solved it for me. Was a bit hesitant given that the repo is just from a researcher, but it's got my R working again, so many, many thanks!

Comment: There's actually an alternative suggestion to installing that gfortran link. That is, to use the version of gfortran that brew provides with gcc, but I think this requires different makevars lines to those provided above. See this link: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/96135

Comment: Glad you got it working @Florag! Sorry I was offline over Christmas/New Year's and couldn't help you solve the issue. My understanding was that `brew reinstall gcc` linked  brew's 'gcc' fortran to /usr/local/gfortran but apparently that's not the case on other people's systems - thanks @speleo for the additional troubleshooting!

Comment: @speleo and @jared_mamrot, you both saved me, thank you! I get the message `ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.16)` after using the fresh gfortran linked. Do you also?

Comment: @user551504 that warning is related to the statically linked llvm libraries. You can avoid the warning by removing llvm (`brew uninstall llvm`) and the references to llvm from the .R/Makevars file, and many packages will still compile but some will fail. Unfortunately, there are still some packages that I couldn't get to compile after following these steps - e.g. rstan - but the majority of packages compile successfully.

Comment: @jared_mamrot what if it says `Error: unexpected symbol in "sudo rm"` in the first step?

Answer (score 2):

**MacOS Ventura 13.5**
Found and tried many different solutions for multiple hours, also the one presented above. The solution for me was to remove the problematic directory from the Terminal.

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs
rm -rf MacOSX.sdk
```

If you are unsure, you can rename the directory, instead of deleting it

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs
sudo mv MacOSX.sdk MacOSX_old.sdk
```

Comment: Thanks @obruzzi! I just ran into this problem myself. Your approach is good (+1) - it'll fix the problem - but I suspect the fix will be 'temporary' i.e. until the next macOS update. I think it would be better in the long run to use the new SDK and the newest GCC - I've edited my post to show how to do that (although, if your method is working, probably best not to mess with it until it breaks again). Thanks for posting your solution!