# Install "gradethis" package for code checking in "learnr"

Tags: r, learnr

I am creating the interactive tutorials for R for presentation using "learnr" package. For code checking, I need the package "gradethis". When I try to install this package by

"
remotes::install_github("rstudio-education/gradethis")
"

it gives the error message:
.
.
.

** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
namespace ‘learnr’ 0.10.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.10.1.9007 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘gradethis’
─  removing ‘/private/var/folders/r2/3nmkgqc51q54tmhxl00tsk2908fpk9/T/RtmpaPONJB/Rinst15003850258d/gradethis’
-----------------------------------
ERROR: package installation failed
Error: Failed to install 'gradethis' from GitHub:
.
.
.

The error message shows "‘learnr’ 0.10.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.10.1.9007 is required", however on CRAN, 0.10.1 is the latest version:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/learnr/index.html

Can anyone help for this case? Many thanks.

The following show `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1       rjson_0.2.20         plyr_1.8.6          
 [4] markdown_1.1         htmltools_0.5.1.9000 tools_3.5.1         
 [7] base64enc_0.1-3      yaml_2.2.1           Rcpp_1.0.6          
[10] rmarkdown_2.6        knitr_1.31           xfun_0.20           
[13] digest_0.6.27        tutorial_0.4.3       rlang_0.4.10.9000   
[16] evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: "learnr" works fine, but I can not install "gradethis" package after install "learnr".

Answer (score 3):

Since [gradethis](https://rstudio.github.io/gradethis/) is still in a developmental/experimental phase, it is currently only available through GitHub at [rstudio/gradethis](https://github.com/rstudio/gradethis/). gradethis currently requires the developmental version of [learnr](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr) which is also not yet on CRAN.

Installing both packages from their GitHub repositories will likely resolve your issues:

```r
# install.packages("remotes") # require {remotes}
remotes::install_github("rstudio/learnr")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/gradethis")
```

Edit: The gradethis repository is now hosted under the `rstudio` GitHub organization.

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced the error (macOS Big Sur 11.1 / Rstudio 1.3.1093 / R version 4.0.3) and solved the issue by uninstalling learnr with `remove.packages("learnr")` then installing gradethis with dependencies (including the required version of learnr) using `remotes::install_github("rstudio-education/gradethis")`.

If you get a warning that "Skipping install of 'gradethis' from a github remote, the SHA1 has not changed since last install", use the command `remotes::install_github("rstudio-education/gradethis", force = TRUE)`

Successfully installing the packages requires the ability to compile from source (instructions for macOS Big Sur: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340)

Comment: Thanks. By following your suggestion, the package "gradethis" is installed. But when I load it, it gives similar message:                                                                                                          

> library(gradethis)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gradethis’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘learnr’ 0.10.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.10.1.9007 is required

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I followed Step 1, 2 and 3. It gives me the error. "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gradethis’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): namespace ‘learnr’ 0.10.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.10.1.9007 is required "

Comment: it is too long for comment, I will attach out put below.

Comment: I see. I will add it in question. Thanks.