# RStudio can't install packages due to C-related errors

Tags: r, c, installation, rstudio, clang++

I'm trying to install a package in RStudio from Github ([this package called FEct](https://yiqingxu.org/software.html)) and getting errors related to the XCode Command Line tools.

The errors:

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:321:9: error: no member named 'isnan' in the global namespace

and errors like this for other cmath functions, in addition to

> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/arma_cmath.hpp:42:15: error: expected unqualified-id

and several very similar errors.

Things I've tried:
When I run `xcrun --show-sdk-path` I get

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

When I run `clang++ -v` I get

```
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/MyName/opt/anaconda3/bin
```

I am trying to install from the RStudio editor (downloaded from the official R website, rather than the one installed by Anaconda Navigator). I recently updated my Mac to OSX Big Sur, version 11.2.

Comment: First of all welcome to this community!
it seems for me that an depency of your package is not installed correctly which might be cmath. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1555092/cmath-compilation-errors-with-clang-10-on-mac-os-catalina) a maybe similar problem is stated

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I just tried that approach (edit cmath file to #include a specific path to math.h, instead of just #include <math.h> and unfortunately it doesn't work. I still get the same errors.

Comment: Unfortunately the macOS Big Sur update caused a number of issues compiling code; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340 for a potential solution