# Unable to install "RecordLinkage" in R version 3.5.0 on MacOs

Tags: r, install.packages, record-linkage

I am trying to install package "RecordLinkage" in Mac but I get this error message.
I already tried to type "no" for "Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?" and it does not work either.
Any advice/suggestions, please?

```
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘RecordLinkage’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source package ‘RecordLinkage’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RecordLinkage_0.4-12.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 759438 bytes (741 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 741 KB

* installing *source* package ‘RecordLinkage’ ...
** package ‘RecordLinkage’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RecordLinkage’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RecordLinkage’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RecordLinkage’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/sp/jy_rk5ts16sbrlkd2mbpg0m00000gn/T/RtmpDWiWEt/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing the xcrun tool.  Do you have Xcode installed?

Comment: If you have Xcode installed, try `sudo xcode-select --install` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/12957340 for more details). If it still fails to install, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340 for a step-by-step guide for building R packages on macOS Big Sur from source.