# Update R into 4.0 version or more due to 3.4.4 package incompatibility? Gviz

Tags: r, rstudio, version, install.packages

I currently have R version 3.4.4 on my R Studio on my MacOS Mojave version 10.14 but I am trying to download R version > 4. I need this because the package Gviz will only work on 4+ R version. Any suggestions on how to download R version > 4 would be highly appreciated.

I have already used the following methods but they have not worked:

**Method 1**

```
RStudio.Version() 
install.packages("installr") 
library(installr) 
updateR()
```

**Method 2**

From within RStudio, went to Help > Check for Updates to install newer version of RStudio (if available, optional).
To update packages, went to Tools > Check for Package Updates. If updates are available, select All (or just tidyverse), and clicked Install Updates.

With both methods I ended up with R version 3.4.4 but I need R version >4

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just [download R](https://cloud.r-project.org/)?

Comment: I am using MacOS Mojave version 10.14

Comment: I download R and the newest version but it just gives me R version 3.4.4 for some reason.

Comment: As @r2evans suggested, first install the latest version of R, than go to Tools -> Global Options, and switch the R Version to the version you installed (4.1.0).

Comment: @Phil where is the R Version on the Global Options?

Comment: Literally the first line: https://i.imgur.com/nYKeDu8.png

Comment: Unfortunately it does not show that it only shows R sessions and then below it has Default working directory (when not in a project):

Comment: If RStudio is not offering a newer version, that means that either (a) the R-4 install did not complete successfully, or (b) it is not visible in your system PATH. Realize that RStudio cannot see changes to the env-vars unless it is restarted, so perhaps restarting RStudio will allow it to see the differences. If not, then you need to handle that as a different problem (https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Rcmd-is-not-found-in-my-PATH_0021).

Answer (score 1):

These steps are usually the quickest way to resolve issues installing/updating R (macOS):

- Uninstall R.
- Uninstall RStudio.
- Restart your computer.
- Download and install R from https://cloud.r-project.org/ (first link:
  https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/base/R-4.1.0.pkg).
- Download and install RStudio from
  https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download (link:
  https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/macos/RStudio-1.4.1717.dmg).
- Open R from your Applications folder and check version is correct.
- Open RStudio from your Applications folder and check version matches.
- Download the Xcode app from the app store.
- Install the command line tools by typing `xcode-select --install`
  into the terminal, or install via the Xcode app, or use your apple ID
  to download and install the command line tools from
  https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.
- Re-install all your R packages.
- If you are unable to build a package from source, follow these
  steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340.

If you've completed these steps and are still having difficulties then it's time to ask for help.