# Error while attempting to install "tidyverse" to RStudio on MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.4

Tags: r, compiler-errors, tidyverse

I have been attempting to download tidyverse all day with no luck. I am a newbie, but have searched for all sorts of remedies and nothing's done the trick yet. This is the initial error message I receive:

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘colorspace’
```

Upon attempting to install colorspace I receive:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘colorspace’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/colorspace’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘colorspace’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/f9/rwtzxt9j7218k7k5vy3r03zm0000gn/T/RtmpFYYSDK/downloaded_packages’
```

No idea what to do about this, am happy to provide more info. Installing directly from the packages tab is also not working.

Comment: At your mac terminal, try typing `xcode-select --install` You need to have xcode installed and configured to build packages from source. you can also try `install.packages("colorpsace", type="binary")` if you don't want to compile (which I might recommend because it's less of a hastle)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I receive this error: ```> install.packages("colorpsace", type="binary")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘colorpsace’ is not available as a binary package for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages```

Comment: Oops. I typed the package name incorrectly. It should be `install.packages("colorspace", type="binary")`. the main point being use `type="binary"` when you use `install.packages`

Comment: No worries! What does this mean?   
` There is a binary version available (and will be installed) but the source version is
  later:
           binary source
colorspace  2.0-1  2.0-2

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/colorspace_2.0-1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2609394 bytes (2.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.5 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
 /var/folders/f9/rwtzxt9j7218k7k5vy3r03zm0000gn/T//RtmpFYYSDK/downloaded_packages  `

Comment: Unfortunately it is 4.1. Downloaded it today!

Comment: The message means there are updated source files available for the pacakge that have not yet been compiled on CRAN. If you you want to install from source, you need to set your machine up to compile pacakges. Normally CRAN takes care of all of that for you. There is a small window after a new release when the CRAN binaries are behind. It's usually totally find just to install the binary version.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry for all of these questions - but how would I do that? Does the same likely apply to all of tidyverse

Comment: Depending on the R package, installing from source on macOS can be quite challenging (e.g. instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340) - if there is a binary available it is often recommended you install the binary as MrFlick said in his first comment.

Comment: That message means that you did that. Tryin `library(tidyverse)` again. At the very least you should get a different error message if it doesn't work, but hopefully it will work.

Comment: Ah. Received this!: ``` ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.1 ──
✓ ggplot2 3.3.4     ✓ purrr   0.3.4
✓ tibble  3.1.2     ✓ dplyr   1.0.7
✓ tidyr   1.1.3     ✓ stringr 1.4.0
✓ readr   1.4.0     ✓ forcats 0.5.1
── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag() ```

Comment: Sorry, format of that is difficult to read: I received two "tidyverse conflicts" : 

x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()

x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

Comment: Those conflicts are fine. Everything is working. You've loaded the tidyverse.