# Installing R on OSX Big Sur (EDIT: and Apple M1) for use with Rcpp and openMP

Tags: r

There's probably a gazillion threads on OSX+Rcpp+openMP, but the bottom line right now appears to be this (per [coatless](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos)):

> Unfortunately, with R 4.0.0 the CRAN distributed version of R loses
> the ability to use OpenMP without a custom setup.

I came across other ideas, including compiling [llvm](https://openmp.llvm.org) yourself, using [homebrew](https://brew.sh) or [macports](https://www.macports.org) to install R and/or llvm and/or gcc, and then figuring out how to use the right compiler and/or flags with (R)cpp. However, I find this all very confusing.

I am not a mac user, but it seems to me that setting up a mac to compile Rcpp packages or code snippets with openMP seems to be too difficult for most mac users. However, I would like my R package on github to be used by more users, and since it relies on openMP, I am losing that audience.

Can someone provide the necessary steps to set up R on mac in a way that it can compile Rcpp code with openMP? I'd like to turn that into a quick tutorial.

EDIT: I should have added - on Apple Silicon, because there are some extra confusions where things go - `/usr/local` vs `/opt`

Comment: For others who find their way here: I have written up instructions appropriate for both Big Sur _and_ Monterey [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70638118). The details on Monterey aren't fundamentally different but there are some complications.

Comment: Thank you Mikael! I haven't tried it yet, specifically because I expected new complications ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eventually, I found a process that works on a **M1 mac** with Big Sur.

- Head over to https://mac.r-project.org/, it contains most things you will need
- Download and **install R** via `R-4.1-branch.pkg`. The CRAN version might also work, but I used the installer from mac.r-project.org, which required opening the *osx security settings* to allow the installation.
- **Install RStudio**, start it, and let it **install the developer tools**. Alternatively, run `sudo xcode-select --install` in Terminal.
- Head to https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/. Download `openmp-11.0.1-darwin20-Release.tar.gz` and install it (see Terminal commands below).

```sh
curl -O https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/openmp-11.0.1-darwin20-Release.tar.gz
sudo tar fvx openmp-11.0.1-darwin20-Release.tar.gz -C /
```

- Now we need to **add compiler flags** so that clan uses openMP. In Terminal, create the `Makevars` file.

```sh
cd ~
mkdir .R
nano .R/Makevars
```

in nano, paste these additional compiler flags into the `Makevars` file:

```
CPPFLAGS += -Xclang -fopenmp
LDFLAGS += -lomp
```

Hit Control+O, Control+X to save and close

- Head over to the gfortran page: https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases
- Use the installer `gfortran-ARM-11.0-BigSur.pkg` to **install gfortran**.
- For some reason it appears to install in `/usr/local/gfortran`, but R expects it in `/opt`. The mac-R team likes to separate arm64 and intel related files. We could go and fix paths, or simply also install gfortran under `/opt`. Download  the tar file `gfortran-ARM-11.0-BigSur.tar.xz`. You can use curl, or just download it and point tar in the command line to it.

```sh
cd /opt/R/arm64/
sudo mkdir gfortran
sudo tar -xzyf gfortran-ARM-11.0-BigSur.tar.xz -C /opt/R/arm64/
```

(replace `gfortran-ARM-11.0-BigSur.tar.xz` with `/users/YOURUSERNAME/downloads/gfortran-ARM-11.0-BigSur.tar.xz`)

Now it *should* work.

Not an expert in OSX, but doing this so others can figure out how to use my R package. I'd like to streamline the process some more, but wiping the mac, reinstalling osx and testing it takes so much time.

Answer (score 15):

I spent a day figuring this out (original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340)); here are the steps I used to compile R packages from source with openMP:

1. Install xcode from the app store ([instructions for installing xcode](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-download-and-install-xcode/)) then install/reinstall the xcode command line tools from the terminal:

```
# To delete an existing command line tools installation:
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

# To install the command line tools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

2. Install gcc via Homebrew ([instructions for installing Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)) or, if you already have gcc installed, skip to step 3.

```
# WARNING: This can take several hours
brew install gcc
```

3. To avoid "legacy" version issues:

```
brew cleanup
brew update
brew upgrade
brew reinstall gcc
```

4. Link some headers into /usr/local/include

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/* /usr/local/include/

# You can ignore warnings like this:
#ln: /usr/local/include//tcl.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclPlatDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMath.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMathDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tk.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tkDecls.h: File exists
#ln: /usr/local/include//tkPlatDecls.h: File exists
```

5. Check your version of gfortran (`cd /usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/; ls`) then edit your `~/.R/Makevars` file (if you don't have a file called `Makevars` in your `~/.R/` directory) and include only these lines:

```
LOC = /usr/local/gfortran
CC=$(LOC)/bin/gcc -fopenmp
CXX=$(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp
CXX11 = $(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp

CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
LDFLAGS=-L$(LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LOC)/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I$(LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include

# (check that the version of gfortran - in this case 10.2.0 - matches the version specified in FLIBS)
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
CXX1X=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX98=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX11=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX14=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX17=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
```

6. Open R and install a package to test that it compiles with openMP enabled (when asked, compile from source = "Yes"):

```
install.packages("data.table", type = "source")
```

Unfortunately, I do not believe a more "simple" setup exists.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for missing the original post. Also, why brew and not macports?

Comment: You are using Homebrew. Can you comment on whether you think this will succeed with the "standard" R provided by CRAN? (The usual advice from Simon Urbanek regarding Homebrew (or MacPorts for that matter) is "don't do that".)

Comment: My general advice regarding OSX is "don't use it". However, it's too late for that, so we have to make do with what people have. I am trying to follow jared's steps, but gfortran seems to be in a different directory. Homebrew apparently puts stuff under /opt instead of /usr/local where it belongs.

Comment: And I just came across another tutorial https://yiqingxu.org/public/BigSurError.pdf

Comment: When you install/reinstall gcc I believe it moves gfortran to /usr/local. On my original post some folks had the same issue and solved it by just installng gfortran from e.g. https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/10.2-bigsur-intel

Comment: Yes, that would install gfortran. However, I thought gcc is part of that gfortran installer. Wouldn't that overwrite/conflict with the installation from brew?

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear - gfortran is bundled with gcc. When you install via homebrew (`brew install gcc`) it should install it (or symlink, I can't remember) into /usr/local/, but some people ran into trouble with that step and had to do a 'clean install' of gfortran. I don't believe this would overwrite the homebrew gfortran, because the homebrew gfortran wasn't in the 'right spot'.

Comment: I see. And why do we need llvm? I looks like your Makevars uses gcc, and not clang. So why is llvm needed?

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember - I had to use the llvm clang to compile specific packages when gcc failed, but I don't remember the specifics. Perhaps llvm provides required headers / libraries? I'll look into it and get back to you

Comment: Speakin of Simon, he seems to prefer the clang route: https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/

Comment: Based on my previous .R/Makevars files, I used llvm to compile rstan with openMP enabled back in 2020 when gcc failed, but I suspect you could skip the llvm install. For your use-case (installing a single specific package) perhaps the https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/ route would be best - you don't really need to worry about compiling other packages - that would definitely be simpler

Comment: I followed mac.r-project, but it doesn't work either. The apple silicon gfortran installer installs into /usr/local instead of /opt/R/arm64, and manually untaring gfortran into the right place doesn't resolve it either, because somehow the compiler looks in opt/ and usr/local. Bottom line: don't use OSX for serious work.

Comment: Ohh - sorry - my answer won't work on Apple M1 silicon - I didn't realise this was your intended goal. And I agree with you on the macOS thing. I use two work laptops: my work-supplied one (macOS) and my own (linux) and I find myself using my own linux laptop pretty regularly when something causes errors on macOS...

Comment: It was my mistake, I didn't clearly state it. However, you really helped me understand a few challenges, and I eventually found a solution. It's quite a shame that Apple makes it so hard, the performance of the M1 is really good once you get it to work.

Comment: Just in case this is useful for others. I use Big Sur and tried to install data.table following your instruction, but while I was able to do every single step the `install.package("data.table")` never installed a version that utilises OpenMP. Only after using `install.packages("data.table", type = "source", repos = "https://Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table")`, was I able to install a multi threaded version.

Comment: Thank you @krenz! Yes, the install.packages command should include `type = "source"` - I've edited my post to fix that issue - thanks for your comment!