# install R package "factoextra"in MAC

Tags: r, pca, factoextra, factominer, mca

I am trying install package " facto extra", but there are some error.
can you please help me to solute the problem.

```
 * installing *source* package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c lpmvnorm.c -o lpmvnorm.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c ltMatrices.c -o ltMatrices.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
/opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran -mtune=native -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
make: /opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [mvt.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvtnorm’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/mvtnorm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘flashClust’ ...
** package ‘flashClust’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
/opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran -mtune=native -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c hc.f -o hc.o
make: /opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [hc.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘flashClust’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/flashClust’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘flashClust’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘leaps’ ...
** package ‘leaps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
/opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran -mtune=native -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c leaps.f -o leaps.o
make: /opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [leaps.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘leaps’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/leaps’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘leaps’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘emmeans’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/emmeans’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘emmeans’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘emmeans’, ‘flashClust’, ‘leaps’ are not available for package ‘FactoMineR’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/FactoMineR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘FactoMineR’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘FactoMineR’ is not available for package ‘factoextra’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/factoextra’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘factoextra’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/7h/gxc3t42541x2pxgl83xqfnx00000gn/T/Rtmpz8Gydy/downloaded_packages’
```

I also tries `install.packages("factoextra",repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")` but it did not work.

Comment: Looks like the first error is that `gfortran` is not found, which prevents the installation of `mvtnorm`. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639782/installing-gfortran-on-macbook-with-apple-m1-chip-for-use-in-r help?

Comment: Agreed, everything after `make: /opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran: No such file or directory` is unnecessary. Fix that problem them reattempt. (Additional link to what bretauv offered: https://www.cynkra.com/blog/2021-03-16-gfortran-macos/, mostly the same suggestions.)