# Install and Load "mice" Package

Tags: r, r-mice

I am trying to install and load the "mice" package, however, this error keeps coming up.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
there is no package called ‘lme4’
```

I am wondering if it has to do with my version of R or something else.

I tried to run the code multiple different ways. I ran the code install.packages("lme4") and that did not work either. I tried to uninstall and reinstall rstudio but nothing is working. I am wondering if anyone has a solution to this error.

Comment: Run `install.packages("lme4")` and try again.

Comment: Also, uninstalling and reinstalling Rstudio is beside the point, it's just an IDE for R.

Comment: Show use the output of `install.packages("lme4")`. Were there any errors?

Comment: Perhaps you're working on a MAC and miss `gcc`, see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69639782/6574038) .