# How do I fix this error being caused by the 'openair' package?

Tags: r, openair

I am attempting to pull data from the U.S. EPA using the 'openair' package.
I have installed 'interp' and 'openair', but I continue to get this error:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openair’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘interp’

I am currently using the most up to date version of Rstudio and I have updated all of my packages as well.   I have also tried removing the packages to re-install them, but I get this error when I try to remove the packages:
Removing package from ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Removing package from ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Error in remove.packages : there is no package called ‘interp’
Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Try running `install.packages("interp")`. Either that will work or the error message should change.

Comment: I have tried using install.packages("interp") and I don't receive any error. I get a data.frame that says:
 
binary
<chr>
source
<chr>
needs_compilation
<lgl>
interp 1.1-5 1.1-6 TRUE

Comment: That doesn't seem right. That's not what `install.packages` should be returning. What if you explicitly call `utils::install.packages("interp")` Is it asking you if you want to install from source? Maybe link to a screen shot of what you are seeing. What version of R are you using?

Comment: Sure thing. Here is the link: https://imgur.com/a/3kJrA4Q

Comment: Oh. Ok. You aren't seeing the error in the document because you are using a markdown document or something. The real error is below in the console. It doesn't look like your mac is setup to compile R packages from source. you could try `install.packages("interp", type="binary")` but that depends on what R version and OS you have. Otherwise you may need to install `gfortran` something like what's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639782/installing-gfortran-on-macbook-with-apple-m1-chip-for-use-in-r It would be better to get the full text of the output from the console first.

Comment: Ok! So I opened an R script and put in the install.package code that you sent over and it worked. It looks like I am now able to pull data from the U.S. EPA. Strange because I am usually able to install and open packages in my Rmarkdown file. Thanks so much for your help!!!