Failing to compile package from Mac
I'm trying to install a package in R, and I get the following error:
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

This, is after I got an error:
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0' not found
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib' not found
ld: library 'gfortran' not found

From my understanding this is an issue of the compiler. So I edited .R/Makevars to point towards the correct compiler (GCC). If I understand correctly, it should support OpenMP.
This is currently my Makevars file:
# This file's location is ~/.R/Makevars
# Default variables (no omp)
# Also potentially CXX11 (for C++11 compiler)
# CXX11=/usr/bin/clang++

# I followed the instructions at http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ to install gcc 4.9
CC=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-14    
CXX=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-14
FC=/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran
F77=/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran

PKG_LIBS = -fopenmp -lgomp
PKG_CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp
CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp

SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS=-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp

I've seen some other questions about the topic, but they were either directly related to data.table package. Or they didn't solve the issue.

Already tried https://stackoverflow.com/q/69639782/6574038?

Yes. I had to compile it.

What worked for me is setting the compiler paths directly:
# This file's location is ~/.R/Makevars
# Default variables (no omp)

CC=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-14 
CXX=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-14 
FC=/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran 
F77=/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran 
FLIBS=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/14  

Not sure if it has openMP support or not, but it allowed me to compile the package.
