Installing Matrix
I run into multiple issues when I try to install version 1.6-3 of Matrix (need the older version for a separate package).
I tried:
remotes::install_version("Matrix", version = "1.6-3")

This error is coming up:

ld: warning: search path '/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current' not found
ld: library 'gfortran' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Not sure how to fix it; I have gfortran and gcc installed. I noticed others had a similar problem but none of the solutions seem to be working for 4.3.3 version of R.

If on Mac, have you used the gfortran installer .pkg? https://mac.r-project.org/tools/ or if on Windows, have you installed RTools? (e.g., RTools 4.3 if using R 4.3) R can be very opinionated on its compiler versions and locations. Or if on linux sudo apt-get install r-base-dev for getting the right dependencies. Generally without some intervention, R will not pick up on homebrew versions. Just noticed you are probably on Mac then.

I do have a Mac, and I did try installking the .pkg gfortran installer with the same issue coming up

Hmm, did you install the binary from CRAN, or install a different way or from source? Not sure if this will help but I'd check the location given by Sys.getenv("R_HOME") (in R console) and go to etc in that directory. For me it's /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc. Check Makeconf and Renviron, helpful in showing how your installation may have been compiled. This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72997915/6780593 . Also worth checking if you already have ~/.R/Makevars that exists that may be modifying anything? You may be able to fix or delete this file

Also just learned you can type R CMD config in the terminal and it will show you a help page for configuration variables you can check the value of, then check R CMD config FC and R CMD config FLIBS
