# Problems installing R package "nloptr" on M1 mac

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to install the "lme4" library in R and RStudio, which worked before I was on an M1 Mac, but now it's not installing. The dependency that's having trouble is: "nloptr". Here's my current error:

````
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/R/arm64/lib -o nloptr.so init_nloptr.o nloptr.o test-C-API.o test-runner.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.2.0/11.0.0 -L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lemutls_w -lm -Lnlopt/lib -lnlopt -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lnlopt/lib'
ld: library not found for -lnlopt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [nloptr.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nloptr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/nloptr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/ht/y6qd6yfn67x086jtwxvh42tw0000gn/T/RtmpULtpZq/downloaded_packages’ ```
````

I'm on an M1 Mac with Monterey (12.1). I've installed the arm64 version of R. Here's my current version R 4.1.2:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       aarch64-apple-darwin20      
arch           aarch64                     
os             darwin20                    
system         aarch64, darwin20           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

I've already tried the following in Terminal: `brew install nlopt` and `brew install gcc`.

Before this, I also had an error as follows:
`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.2.0/11.0.0'`
To fix that, based on Googling, I did this
`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/bin`
and this
`` ln -sfn `xcrun --show-sdk-path` /opt/R/arm64/gfortran/SDK ``

Comment: If it continues to not work, it might be worth posting an issue at https://github.com/astamm/nloptr/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my machine (an M1 Mac running Big Sur), I've just tried `install.packages("nloptr")` *without* first doing `brew install nlopt`.

I get the same warning about `-Lnlopt/lib`:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lnlopt/lib'
ld: library not found for -lnlopt
clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [nloptr.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nloptr’
```

but prior to the warning I see:

```
checking if pkg-config knows NLopt... no
using NLopt via local cmake build on arm64

------------------ CMAKE NOT FOUND --------------------

CMake was not found on the PATH. Please install CMake:

 - yum install cmake          (Fedora/CentOS; inside a terminal)
 - apt install cmake          (Debian/Ubuntu; inside a terminal).
 - pacman -S cmake            (Arch Linux; inside a terminal).
 - brew install cmake         (MacOS; inside a terminal with Homebrew)
 - port install cmake         (MacOS; inside a terminal with MacPorts)

Alternatively install CMake from: <https://cmake.org/>

-------------------------------------------------------
```

`install.packages("nloptr")` succeeds after I install CMake with `brew install cmake`.

As for your initial issue with `gfortran`, I might suggest trying my instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70638118). R recommends installing a specific build of `gfortran` and configuring compilers to find that installation via `~/.R/Makevars`. You really should not need to mess with your `PATH`...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `brew install cmake` didn't help me, nor did installing `nloptr` from source, nor did configuring RStudio to use the correct `PATH`.

[According to the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nloptr/versions/2.0.3), in the section labeled **Installing CMake (macOS and Linux only)**, the nloptr package installer expects to find the `cmake` executable either at:

1. The path specified by the `CMAKE_BIN` environment variable (spoiler alert: setting it didn't work), or
2. `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake`.

Here's how I finally resolved the problem in a `zsh` shell:

```
brew install cmake
sudo mkdir -p /Applications/cmake.app/Contents/bin
cd /Applications/cmake.app/Contents/bin
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake
```

The downside to this approach is that it puts a non-application in the `/Applications` directory, but that I can live with.