# Trouble installing lme4 package in R

Tags: r, installation, package, lme4

I am having trouble installing the `lme4` package. `install.packages("lme4")` issues the below warnings. When I try to load `lme4`, R says that it is non-existent. Does anyone know how to address this?

```
also installing the dependency `nloptr`

Warning message in install.packages("lme4"):
“installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("lme4"):
“installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status”
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
    
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Comment: Can you run `install.packages("nloptr")` and copy and paste the _full_ output into your question? It would also help to see the output of `sessionInfo()`. You can find a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881723). You may just need to install or update CMake, but how you would do that is platform-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider `sudo apt install r-cran-lme4` as the `lme4` is of course part of every Debian and Ubuntu release, has been [since 2004](https://salsa.debian.org/edd/r-cran-lme4/-/blob/master/debian/changelog#L774-779).  And that does of course include its dependencies, and eg `nloptr` has been in Debian and Ubuntu [since 2014](https://salsa.debian.org/edd/r-cran-nloptr/-/blob/master/debian/changelog#L94-L100). (Disclosure: I maintain both for Debian).

More generally, you may also consider binaries for Ubuntu. I just answered a similar question yesterday [with a nice 'gif video'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75838035/cant-install-gmm-package-in-r-ubuntu-22-04) of how installing the `gmm` package off the [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) repository with its 20,000 CRAN binaries for Ubuntu is something you may want to consider.

Answer (score -1):

lme4 is trying to install a dependency `nloptr`, `nloptr` does need an external dependency to be installed called `cmake`, this could be why an installation of `lme4` is failing.

If you capture the error of the package installation, you might see something like this:

```
CMake was not found on the PATH. Please install CMake:

 - sudo yum install cmake          (Fedora/CentOS; inside a terminal)
 - sudo apt install cmake          (Debian/Ubuntu; inside a terminal).
 - sudo pacman -S cmake            (Arch Linux; inside a terminal).
 - sudo brew install cmake         (MacOS; inside a terminal with Homebrew)
 - sudo port install cmake         (MacOS; inside a terminal with MacPorts)

Alternatively install CMake from: <https://cmake.org/>
```

You can try one of the options above, depending on your operating system.