# RcppExports.o Error 127 when trying to install Monocle3

Tags: r, macos, installation, rcpp

I'm unable to install monocle3, and I'm getting this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘monocle3’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_1/bin/g++-7 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
/bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_1/bin/g++-7: No such file or directory
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘monocle3’
```

My R version is:

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin17.0"
$arch
[1] "x86_64"
$os
[1] "darwin17.0"
$system
[1] "x86_64, darwin17.0"
$status
[1] ""
$major
[1] "4"
$minor
[1] "1.3"
$year
[1] "2022"
$month
[1] "03"
$day
[1] "10"
$`svn rev`
[1] "81868"
$language
[1] "R"
$version.string
[1] "R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)"
$nickname
[1] "One Push-Up"
```

I really have no idea how to solve this issue. Any help or suggesions are appreciated!

I tried reinstalling Rcpp before installing monocle3, but it didn't work.
Thank you!

Comment: Please see https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/ and well as some the YouTube! videos by @coatless.  You are on macOS which means that you need to take care of a setup.  Linux is easier.

Comment: Thank you @Dirk Eddelbuettel! I will go over those YouTube videos and see if it works.

Comment: I also find this answer super helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70638118/configuring-compilers-on-mac-m1-big-sur-monterey-for-rcpp-and-other-tools

Comment: That is a nice answer and there are a number of these here -- it is sadly a pretty common problem for macOS users.