# Installing tidyverse package - how do i deal with this message?

Tags: r, tidyverse

When I try to install tidyverse I get this message about binary versions being available.

I don't know which answer to give, and I don't actually know how I answer? I am just learning R as of this week.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNRWN.png)

Comment: Start by saying "No", then if everything installs ok (i.e. you can load the package using `library(tidyverse)` and don't get any errors) I would leave it at that. If you want to be able to install packages from source you typically need rtools (windows) or command line tools (macOS). Guide for macOS Big Sur here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340. This questions isn't really suited to stackoverflow (this forum is more geared toward professional programmers), but if you need help the R community is a great place to start for this type of question (https://community.rstudio.com/)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code/errors. This makes it impossible to search in the future. If it asks you if you want to install from sources it's usually best to say "no". It's much harder to get your computer set up to compile packages.