# Is Makevars file required to be in ~/.R folder to successfully compile packages?

Tags: r, clang

**Note**: I am running R 4.1.1 on macOS Big Sur 11.4. I have installed both Xcode 12.5.1 and Command Line Tools 12.5.1.0.1.1623191612.

I recently deleted my R Makevars file in the ~/.R directory using

```
sudo rm ~/.R/Makevars
```

because it was interfering with my updated clang12 compiler (the original Makevars was using clang4).

When I type

```
devtools::has_devel()
```

everything is fine. Output says

```
Your system is ready to build packages!
```

However, a number of errors are generated when I try to compile my  package to eventually submit a CRAN update.

Because of this, I'm wondering: Is Makevars required to be in ~/.R folder to successfully compile packages?

If so, I'll retrieve and edit the Makevars.

Comment: "A number of errors" ..... ok, that's a start but leaves off crucial details.

Comment: This is a very 'open ended' question; different packages have different requirements. Without further details - e.g. OS/architecture? Which package/packages do you want to install? How did you install clang12? Do you need MPI for parallelisation? Etc - I don't know how to help you with this.

Comment: Looking at your previous questions I can see you've tried a number of things to solve your problem, including my instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340) which have worked for many others in similar situations. You may have a 'bigger problem' causing your issues but we can't help you troubleshoot without specific details. Please provide more details e.g. _what package are you trying to compile?_

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to provide more details. Specifically a snippet of the error messages I receive. I've tried many things, but I wanted to ask this question before creating a Makevars file and populating it with the necessary details.

Comment: It is not required. If you are getting errors you probably have something misconfigured - try reinstalling R to get a new global Makevars. Also it's odd that it is picking clang if you are on linux - perhaps it is assuming your default compiler is gcc and that's why you get errors?

Comment: I'm actually running macOS Big Sur 11.4. Since upgrading to this version, things have been nothing short of painful I'm afraid. Nevertheless, i'll try reinstalling R. That could work.