# Issues installing RcppMP in MacOS

Tags: r

I am trying to install `RcppMP` in MacOS.
However, when I type:

```
remotes::install_github("Thell/RcppMP",dependencies = T)
```

I get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘RcppMP’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/BH/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/RcppMP.h:7:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppMP_RcppExports.h:7:
../inst/include/RcppMP_types.hpp:15:10: fatal error: 'mpreal.h' file not found
#include <mpreal.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppMP’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/RcppMP’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/pq/hxwd9my563q_qpy4rbrlgkmw0000gn/T//RtmpIdnyiB/file2184610d74ea/RcppMP_0.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

My `~/.R/Makevars` file contain the following specifications:

```
    CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
    CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
    CXX1X=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
    LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
    CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include
    FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_1/lib/gcc/11
```

Comment: Try installing the [GNU mpfr library](https://www.mpfr.org/) (easiest method is via homebrew: `brew install mpfr`) and add "-I/usr/local/include" to your CXXFLAGS variable (i.e. `CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -I/usr/local/include`) and add "-L/usr/local/lib" to your LDFLAGS variable (`-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -L/usr/local/lib`). You may also need to install the gmp library (`brew install gmp`); see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251887/clang-7-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-for-macos-big-sur/65334247#65334247 for more details

Comment: So I did try to do as you suggested, adding those lines to the `~/.R/Makevars` but I do get the same error. I made sure that both `mpfr` and `gmp` were installed.

Comment: Thanks for providing all the necessary details; I think I've figured it out. I got it to install successfully on my system so I'll post the steps I used as an answer

Comment: Rcpp maintainer here: I don't see why this is tagged `Rcpp`.  It is mostly a 'how do I compile from source on macOS' question as best as I can tell.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel. Thanks for the comment. I am going to remove the Rcpp tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bit more complicated than I thought; this package requires mpfr, gmp and the very-similarly-named mpfrc++. The steps that worked for me are:

1. Install gmp and mpfr via homebrew
2. Download and unzip "mpfrc++-3.6.8.zip" from
   http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/#download
3. Copy the mpreal header file ("mpreal.h") to
   /usr/local/include (`sudo cp ./mpreal.h /usr/local/include/`) or, in your case, perhaps `sudo cp ./mpreal.h /usr/local/opt/llvm/include` would make more sense
4. Install/compile RcppMP
   (`remotes::install_github("Thell/RcppMP",dependencies = TRUE)`)

I got some warnings but no errors, and the package loaded (`library(RcppMP)`), so I'm relatively confident it installed successfully. If you find otherwise, please let me know and I'll look into it further.

Comment: Your suggestion helped to solve the problem. However, I needed to use the `~/.R/Makevars` from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251887/clang-7-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-for-macos-big-sur/65334247#65334247, with the modifications you suggested. Do you know why clang compilation does not work whereas g++ does work? (if this is the true issue in my case).

Comment: I wrote [the post you got your `~/.R/Makevars` from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251887/clang-7-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-for-macos-big-sur/65334247#65334247) and the whole point of that post was to develop a strategy that worked for 'tricky edge cases'. I think this RcppMP package falls into the 'tricky edge case' category. There is a good chance you could compile it using clang, but you would need to spend time working out the compiler flags etc. Also, you would probably then need to adjust your `~/.R/Makevars` for other packages. Seems easier to just use g++.

Comment: Hi @jared_mamrot, yes I noticed that you wrote that post. I added that comment above just to be clear (also for others that may encounter the same problem). That is, I could install RcppMP using g++ and not clang. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: That makes sense; thanks for clarifying. I'm glad you solved your problem, and I'm glad I could help. this type of 'something isn't quite right' problem can be incredibly frustrating. Thanks for including all the relevant info in your post :)