# Cannot install package Rdpack due to error "had non-zero exit status"

Tags: r, installation

I am using RStudio 2022.02.3 Build 492 for mac. I am trying to install the package Rdpack as a requirement to load another package and it does not work. Could you please help to tell me what the problem is and what I should do to solve it. And here is the error message I received:

```
 install.packages('Rdpack')
also installing the dependency ‘rbibutils’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
rbibutils  2.2.7  2.2.8              TRUE
Rdpack       2.3  2.3.1             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source packages ‘rbibutils’, ‘Rdpack’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rbibutils_2.2.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 882817 bytes (862 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 862 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rdpack_2.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 703156 bytes (686 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 686 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rbibutils’ ...
** package ‘rbibutils’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rbibutils’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rbibutils’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rbibutils’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rbibutils’ is not available for package ‘Rdpack’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rdpack’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rdpack’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/r2/_r7yln992kq1x9pg298ql_s40000gn/T/RtmpMko8Ru/downloaded_packages’
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: RStudio has nothing to do with this - update R (currently at 4.2.1) and try again.

Comment: The line "invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)" suggests you have not installed the [Command Line Tools for macOS](https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/index.html). Install them and then try again. If it still doesn't work, follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @jared_mamrot so much for your help. It really works for my case. I successfully dit it. Yayy!!!